# Default Buffer Max Size and Default Buffer Size in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, ssis-2005

[image]

Is there any relationship between Default Buffer Max rows and Default Buffer Size in SSIS.
How to supply values to these property parameters?

I mean is there any propossionality in between these ?If I double the buffer size double then can i also have to make the max rows to double?
ssis experts please answer..

Here the Oledb source contain 20 million records ,and also the lookup table.I have designed the dataflow with the mentioned buffersize and buffer rows.

Is this the maximum size set up for all the components under the dataflow task?
or is it like once the Lookup completes then it releases the buffer for the next component?

I have doubled the size of buffer and the maxrows,but could not find any performance gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer size is customizable based on memory needed in ssis. The max memory that ssis use is 100 MB. What I would do extra is in OLEDB destination I would define Table or view -Fast load or table name or view name variable -Fast load to boost the load.

The link from [James Serrra's Blog](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/jamesserra/2011/11/30/buffer-size-in-ssis/)

Comment: We don't have any evidence to suggest he's not using `BULK INSERT` already.

Comment: Is 100 MB per data flow or per package?